# Stop Picasa (Mac) from scanning my harddrive

Tags: picasa

I want to use Picasa desktop app instead of the tedious & clunky web interface to share a couple of photos.

Every time I launch Picasa it proceeds to open an annoying pop-up/tool-tip which flicks through **every** file on my HD using <=95% of CPU. I don't want this so I click the X. It appears again. I try to drag it somewhere less annoying onscreen but it pings back. I look in prefs for an option to turn it off. I give up and quit app until a new build comes out, which I download and repeat the above.

WTF?! I understand Google can't be as cool as Apple - iPhoto isn't perfect by any means but at least it looks nice and 'just works'.

I want to launch Picasa, not have it go through everything, not have 1000's of random pics and HD cruft on display in the list, and then perhaps drag in a few photos and upload them.

Any idea of if that is possible? `</rant>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, go to Tools > Folder Manager and choose "Remove from Picasa" on all or some of the folders.

Answer (score 1):

I was offered the option of having Picasa search the entire hard drive or just my home folder the first time I launched the application.

If you chose the Hard Drive option, you could try removing all of Picasa's preference files and starting over so you can choose the Home Folder option... Then once it has found all the files in your home directory, it won't need to search for them again the next time it is launched.

Hmm, additionally, if you right click folders in the Picasa sidebar, there is an option to "Remove from Picasa..." I believe if you remove the folder, it will prevent it from being searched for new photos every time you launch the application.

Comment: Thanks a lot, after writing the rant above I found you can reaccess the scanning list via Tools > Folder Manager, and then choose "Remove from Picasa" for all or some folders. But a mod deleted when I posted it.

Comment: Mmhmm, just make sure to accept one of the answers so the question doesn't appear as "unanswered."